# what does Method getResources not annotated with request type (e.g., GET, POST) mean?

Tags: java, retrofit

```
private interface ResourcesApi {
        @POST("/synchronize")
        void getResources(@Body Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map,
                          Callback<DataModel> callback);
    }
```

with calling code:

```
mApi.getResources(data, this);
```

The class implements Callback so success/failure are defined.

STACKTRACE:

```
03-09 18:05:15.182  28570-28746/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method getResources not annotated with request type (e.g., GET, POST).
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseMethodAnnotations(RestMethodInfo.java:179)
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.init(RestMethodInfo.java:115)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:327)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:262)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:313)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:38)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the `@POST` annotation can't be found at runtime. Without the HTTP method type (and relative URL it contains), Retrofit cannot make the request.

Are you using Proguard or another tool to trim "unused" code? If so, instruct it to keep Retrofit's annotations.

Comment: It was Proguard. Thanks Jake.

Comment: I am facing the same issues, and i am not even using proguard. 
Please can you help? 
POST requests works fine but in GET request gives me this error

Comment: Could you possibly describe what needs to be added toi the proguard config to make this work? I have an interface named 'API' that uses \@POST, \@GET, etc from retrofit, but proguard keeps stripping them

Comment: I've never used ProGuard.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Jake's answer, this is what I had to add to my `proguard` file to get it to work correctly:

```
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
```

Comment: That helps my app to able to make HTTP call and receive data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @chad's answer,  add below lines if still getting crash.

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
```