# Retrofit HTTP reporting "HTTP method annotation is required" in Scala code on Android

Tags: java, android, scala, retrofit

I'm running into an issue where the Retrofit library is recognizing the method but not its annotations. It's reporting the error message in the title above.

(Background:  I'm using SBT with the `sbt-android-plugin` and Retrofit 1.6.1)

My code is like so:

```
private trait MyService {
    @GET("/api/test")
    def test(): Observable[Any]
}

object MyService {
    private val restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://somewhere").build()
    val service = restAdapter.create(classOf[MyService])

    service.test().subscribe(/* you get the idea */) // This line throws a RuntimeException with message in title above
}
```

There's a very similar example scattered around GitHub apparently from the Reactive principles course, e.g. [here](https://github.com/asarcar/functional_and_reactive_programming_course/blob/56964de0b687ee4907792a8c7ddc53002c4b7afe/ReactiveProgramming/class_examples/week4/build.sbt). Suffice it to say, my setup is the same.

When I step through `RestMethodInfo.parseMethodAnnotations()`, the `requestMethod` variable is indeed null, the `requestType` is `SIMPLE`.  If I add the `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation to my test method, the `requestType` is still set to `SIMPLE`.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out Proguard was stripping the annotations.

The advice in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/435) was helpful:

> ```
> -keepattributes *Annotation*
> -keep class retrofit.** { *; }
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
> @retrofit.http.* <methods>; }
> -keepattributes Signature
> ```

And this issue is also mentioned in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288868/what-does-method-getresources-not-annotated-with-request-type-e-g-get-post).

Answer (score 3):

In retrofit:2.0.0 library need to use annotation from `retrofit2` :

```
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
```

Instead of `retrofit` :

```
import retrofit.http.Field;
import retrofit.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit.http.GET;
```