# Using gitskarios/GithubAndroidSdk

Tags: android, github, github-api

I'm trying to use the [gitskarios/GithubAndroidSdk](https://github.com/gitskarios/GithubAndroidSdk) to provide my alpha and beta testers a way to view current github issues and report new ones. Here are the steps I've already taken:

1. Create a GitHub application at [LINK](https://github.com/settings/developers).
2. Add the client info to my application's metadata:

   - com.alorma.github.sdk.client -> my client's ID
   - com.alorma.github.sdk.secret ->  my client's secret
   - com.alorma.github.sdk.oauth -> my client's 'Authorization callback URL'

Run this code in my fragment's onCreate:

```
GithubDeveloperCredentials.init(new MetaDeveloperCredentialsProvider(mParent));
UserReposClient client = new UserReposClient(getActivity(), null);
client.setOnResultCallback(new BaseClient.OnResultCallback<List<Repo>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponseOk(List<Repo> repos, Response response) {
        Log.d("GitHub", "onResponseOK: " + response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFail(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        Log.d("GitHub", "onFail: " + retrofitError);
    }
});
Log.d("GitHub", "getting repos");
client.execute();
```

The result is a single log for "getting repos" and no callback.

I've tried removing the call to `GithubDeveloperCredentials.init()` but that just causes a crash saying that `provider` is null. I then thought that maybe I didn't have an auth token so I made a call to the `RequestTokenClient` using `null` for the second parameter in `RequestTokenClient(Context context, String code)` but this too never gets a callback or return a `null` token if executed with `executeSync()`.

UPDATE

I tried using the Personal access tokens (see comments) page to generate an access token then save it into `StoreCredentials`. When running the `execute()` command now it appears to be getting a little further but now I'm getting a new error saying:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: LoginService.requestToken: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.).
```

Looking around I found an answer (see comments) saying this might be a proguard issue with the retrofit package. So I added those lines into my app's proguard file but no luck yet.

Can anybody help me? All I want to do is get a list of the open issues.

Comment: Why the down vote? How can I make this question clearer?

Comment: Used this page to generate the token: https://github.com/settings/tokens

Comment: Used this answer for the proguard stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830891/retrofit-http-reporting-http-method-annotation-is-required-in-scala-code-on-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I got this working finally though not quite in the best way I wanted. I initially intended each of my Alpha testers to require having their own GitHub account and be added to the project then using their own credentials to obtain an auth token and accessing the bug list. Instead, using the auth token I generated in my update I was able to access the repo. I had to change the proguard to:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
@retrofit.http.* <methods>; }
```

(For some reason the `*Annotation*` and `Signature` nedded to be on the same line)